# I am getting an error while creating a Project of Phonegap through Node.js in my mac

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-cli

I Installed Node Js and Git on my Mac. Through Node JS i am downloading the phonegap and than creating its project on my desktop. Heres what i am getting in return, could somebody tell me what am doing wrong?

```
Aleems-MacBook-Pro:desktop aleemahmad$ phonegap create Cartoonsmart
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/util/connect-proxy.js:21
                fs.readFile(settings, (err, data) => {
                                                  ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/serve.js:9:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
Aleems-MacBook-Pro:desktop aleemahmad$
```

Comment: Update your version of Node.js

Answer (score 0):

For creating new project in Phonegap,
the command is

> phonegap create [foldername] [packagename] [projectname]

For example ::

> phonegap create Demo com.demo Demo.

In this first "Demo" is folder name,
com.demo is package name,
Demo is project name/application name.

Try this, It will work for you.

Thanks